# HttpClient.Timeout and its relation to large transfers

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

### The Scenario

I'm trying to wrap my head around the behaviour of `HttpClient.Timeout`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout.aspx) describes it as *"the number of milliseconds to wait before the request times out"*, but I'm not entirely clear on what is meant by `request`, or what to do if I want more particular control.

One thing I've discovered is that the timeout at least takes account of how long it takes to *send* a request, which is a little frustrating as I'm working with data large enough that the default 100 second timeout isn't enough to send the entire content.

### A Solution That Doesn't Quite Get There

A simple solution might be to increase the timeout substantially, but I'm struck that this could have some highly undesired consequences. Say the client can't establish a connection to the server. Waiting 20 minutes for a connection to be established is absurd, but waiting 20 minutes while a transfer is steadily plodding along is entirely reasonable (for my scenario at least).

### The Question(s)

Is there a way for me to get more granular control over timeout elements of `HttpClient`? Might I have to set the timeout to unlimited and manage timeouts with my own code via the `CancellationToken` or some other mechanism? If I need that level of control, am I better off abandoning `HttpClient` altogether, and going down to the underlying `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` classes?

Comment: If a connection can't be established doesn't HttpClient throw long before the timeout expires.

Comment: Well that's what I'm not really clear on. If a DNS can't be resolved for example, that fails before timeout, or if the server "actively refuses" the connection, likewise, that fails fairly fast. But what about lost packets? If it sends out a request for connection and never gets a response, will it wait the full timeout period?

Comment: If a packet is lost the TCP layer will deal with it and resend. if TCP fails to resend it will eventually timeout and that timeout is unrelated to the timeout in the HttpClient.

Comment: tks Cellfish, Just tried this, set timeout to 24hrs, it fixed large upload issue, then tried unplugging network cable during transfer, and about 30 seconds later it errored out, so yeah, timeout behaviour definitely does not ignore lower level failures.